# Why is this object not in scope?

Tags: javascript, scope, closures, p5.js

See the code example below:

```
( function(){
  var test = new p5(
    function ( p ){
       var x = new Quad(); // Quad is undefined
    }
  ),

  Quad = function(){
     // some code
  }
})();
```

I suspect it has to do with the external library (`p5` in this example) because the anonymous function is executed within the context of `new p5()`, but I don't understand it.

I thought that because `Quad` was defined within the main closure's scope, it should be available to anything defined within that closure...

Can you explain to me why my thinking is wrong?

Comment: it is available, after it's declared and assigned...

Comment: @dandavis — But not before it is assigned, which is rather the point.

Comment: @Quentin: the code could be ok depending on the p5 function, and when it invokes the passed function. the declaration will be closed as the OP expects, but it won't not be undefined until Quad is assigned. if p5 waits just a hair everything is cool as-shown, but if p5 executes right away, then all hope is lost.

Comment: @dandavis — If it waited then there wouldn't be an error, so we know it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't assign a value to `Quad` until *after* you call `p5()`. Presumably it tries to use it immediately, at which point is undefined (it is declared though, since the effects of `var` are already applied).

Switch the order of the two parts of the statement.

```
( function(){
  var  Quad = function(){
     // some code
  }, test = new p5(
    function ( p ){
       var x = new Quad(); // Quad is undefined
    }
  )
})();
```

Or use a function declaration (which will be hoisted) instead.

```
( function(){
  var test = new p5(
    function ( p ){
       var x = new Quad(); // Quad is undefined
    }
  );
// Note semi-colon above. You aren't creating multiple variables with `var` in a single statement any more.
  function Quad (){
     // some code
  }
})();
```

Comment: [A post on hoisting](http://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2013/04/20/javascript-hoisting-explained/)

Comment: Thanks @Quentin - I forgot that variables aren't hoisted the way functions are. Such a basic mistake - I appreciate you providing the examples.

Answer (score 0):

As @Quentin rightly pointed out, this is due to vars not being hoisted, as opposed to functions, which are.

After starting to implement his solution, it got me thinking about code separation and I realized that I should really split the Quad definition out into its own separate JS file.

So I leveraged [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) and rewrote the code to look like this:

```
require("Quad", function(){
  var test = new p5(
    function ( p ){
       var x = new Quad(); // Quad is defined in Quad.js, loaded in via require.js
    }
  )
});
```